# Method not called from on-tap event in polymer2

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

In Polymer1 I used

```
  on-tap="exportAsCsv"
```

in my template! When I use this in a Polymer2 Component (ES6 class syntax) it does not work (Event is not called).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you extending `Polymer.GestureEventListeners`.

You need to extend them in order to use `gesture event`

```
class TestEvent extends Polymer.GestureEventListeners(Polymer.Element) {
```

Please have a look at [documents](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events#using-gesture-events) for more help.

Comment: Thanks... Fixed my Problem